# how can i use an array of values inside where clause in knex?

Tags: node.js, express

How can i use an array of value to compare inside the where clause like in the below code, 'frompersons' is an array of names coming in response from the first call and I want to get out their info from 'chatterusers' database. But how can i use this array inside the next  where clause ?

```
return knex('frndrqst').where({ toperson: toperson })
            .select('fromperson')
            .then(frompersons => {

                  db.select('*').from('chatterusers')
                    .where( 'name', '=', frompersons )
                    .then(data => {
                        res.json(data);
                    })
                    .catch(err => res.json("Unable to load frndrqsts !!!"))
                })
            .catch(err => res.json("Unable to load frndrqsts !!!"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//get the list of name from 'formperson' table 

var subquery = knex.select('name').from('fromperson');

//get in all information from 'chatterusers table' that name is equal with name

return knex.select('*').from('chatterusers')
  .whereIn('name', subquery)
```

**output :**

```
select * from chatterusers where name in (select name from fromperson)
```